# How to find out which version of OpenStack is running on a server?

Tags: command-line-interface, openstack, infrastructure

I am managing an OpenStack mostly through the `openstack` CLI and the permissions to manage specific projects and their resources. Is there a command available to me that can tell me the release name or version number of the OpenStack release running remotely on the OpenStack I am managing?

The CLI version is 5.4.0.

Comment: Since the OpenStack cli only queries the API's I think that at best you can only get API (micro-) versions. Doesn't `nova-manage` show you your OpenStack release?

Answer (score 2):

Currently I don't know a better way than looking into the [release notes](https://releases.openstack.org/) and compare your versions with the ones listed in the details pages. For example, your version of `python-openstackclient` seems to be from the [Victoria release](https://releases.openstack.org/victoria/index.html). Since every component like nova, glance, cinder etc. have their different versions it seems the only way at the moment. If I'm missing some helpful command I'd be glad if someone pointed that out. For example, one could think that the command `openstack versions show` would list your current version, but it does not. I would like to see a command providing the information.

Answer (score 0):

i don't think there is way to find it directly yet the way i check it is i open [releases](https://releases.openstack.org/)
then i check versions of one of the installed module for example i run

> keystone-manage --version

i get "22.0.0"
in the releases link click on one specific release in my case zed cycle as you can see the keystone version is 22.0.0 . just one thing this does not guaranty that i have openstack zed release installed it is possible that new release come out but they didn't upgrade keystone. in that case you should check multiple modules like cinder ,glance ,nova ,etc to verify.